# pyzmq import error

Tags: python, windows-7, pyzmq

I installed `pyzmq` for python in win64 but when I compile it i get a error. What can I do?

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:08:48) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import pyzmq

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyzmq
ImportError: No module named pyzmq
>>>
```

Comment: can you explain how did you install  `pyzmq`?

Comment: i installed in that link. https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=pyzmq&submit=search

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the installation went fine, the module should be available as `zmq`. Try importing that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Windows, please try installing from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyzmq).